# Vertically centering page with @texttop and @textbottom

Tags: vertical-alignment, latex-base

I am trying to use `\@texttop` and `\@textbottom` to vertically center a page in a manner similar to [Use of \@texttop and \@textbottom for vertical positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40469/use-of-texttop-and-textbottom-for-vertical-positioning). Everything works fine if I do

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\def\@texttop{\vskip \z@ plus 1fill\relax}
\def\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ plus 1fill\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

but if I switch `\vskip \z@ plus 1fill\relax` to something like `\vskip \z@ plus 0.5\textheight\relax` or even `\vskip \z@ plus 0.1fil\relax` the page is no longer centered. My guess is there must be some one el stretch sneaking in some place in my MWE, but I cannot figure out where. Why doesn't a stretch of `0.5\textheight` center the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you modify your example

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\showoutput
\showboxdepth=3
\makeatletter
\parfillskip3\p@
\def\@texttop{\vskip \z@ plus 2fil\relax}
\def\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ plus 2fil\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

You see that there is fil glue:

```
ompleted box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(578.15999+0.0)x469.75499
.\glue 0.0
.\vbox(578.15999+0.0)x469.75499
..\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499
..\glue 0.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(578.15999+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 113.632fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 2.0fil
...\glue(\topskip) 3.05556
...\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 239.2044 []
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 2.0fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499
```

This actually comes from `\newpage` via the implict `\clearpage` in `\end{document}`

```
\def \newpage {%
  \if@noskipsec
    \ifx \@nodocument\relax
      \leavevmode
      \global \@noskipsecfalse
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@inlabel
    \leavevmode
    \global \@inlabelfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak \@nobreakfalse \everypar{}\fi
  \par
  \vfil%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \penalty -\@M}
```